# "failed to retrieve share list from server: file already exists" (Can't access samba shares after 18.04) update

Tags: server, 18.04, samba

After upgrading from 16.04 to 18.04 I can't access my samba shares anymore.
I can login with my credential to the samba share (it's an office windows server) but get stuck with the same error:

"failed to retrieve share list from server: file already exists"

Is it possible that I should clean up samba config files?

Thank you

EDIT:
found a workaround (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/thunar/+bug/1762211) typing the full name of the samba share on the address bar give me access to the directory. Still missing the possibility to see the list of samba shares though.

Comment: See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/thunar/+bug/1762211 and https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2164517

Comment: thank you. The workaround in the launchpad bug report works fortunately.

Comment: Post as an answer with a link back to the bug report

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially I found a workaround, typing the full name of the samba share on the address bar give me access to the directory. Apparently there is a related bugreport: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/thunar/+bug/1762211

And here is the full solution:

```
sudo apt install smbclient
```

and then edit /etc/samba/smb.conf right under the workgroup = WORKGROUP line and add this line to change the default:

```
client max protocol = NT1
```

Reference:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2384959

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Comment: don'tt worked for me

Comment: I my case I had to set `server min protocol = NT1`, see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1037897/how-to-force-nautilus-to-use-smb1/1235391#1235391

Answer (score 1):

While setting `client max protocol = NT1` will "work" at least when addressing older machines, enabling SMBv1 called NT1 in samba, and forcing its use (which is what this does) is not a good idea from a security standpoint.

SMBv1 is a really old, deprecated, flawed, and insecure, protocol. 
Reference: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/filecab/2016/09/16/stop-using-smb1/

It's also not going to help to deal with Win10 machines which are now defaulting to simply not having SMBv1 installed, those are likely to respond to `smbclient -L ...` with:

```
protocol negotiation failed: NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_RESET
Failed to connect with SMB1 -- no workgroup available
```

@Francesco Your original "workaround" is actually a better and safer "answer".

Anyway, please don't force SMBv1 :-)

(this would have been more appropriately posted as a comment, however I lack sufficient reputation to do things "properly".)

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I wouldn't otherwise have thought about the security implications of that. Still need a decent way to access my samba share list apparently :)