# Allow SMB 1 with LANMAN authentication with Samba

Tags: samba

I need to connect a DOS machine to a Samba share. On Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial), this is no problem, I just have to add `lanman auth=yes` to `smb.conf` and re-generate the password hashes with smbpasswd. It seems on Ubuntu 19.10 this is broken. Even after this procedure, `pdbedit -L -w` shows 32 times `X` where the LANMAN hash should be. If I copy the TDB-Database (in /var/lib/samba/private) from an Ubuntu Xenial machine, the newer Samba-Version even overwrites the correct LMHASH with 32*`X`. There is no error message and the option `lanman auth=yes` is still accepted by `testparm`, so this seems to be a bug. Is there a way to activate LM-Hashes on newer Ubuntu versions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to force Nautilus to use SMB1?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1037897/how-to-force-nautilus-to-use-smb1)

Comment: @K7AAY This question is about the client, but I'm looking the right configuration for the server

Answer (score 1):

Finally solved it:

```
[global]
   server min protocol = NT1
   ntlm auth = yes
   lanman auth = yes
```

and setting a new password by

```
sudo smbpasswd username
```

solved it as suggested by Morbius1.

But I had two more things to consider:

1. Setting the same password as it was before wont reset the hash.
2. The passwords maximal length is 14 character. With longer passwords the hash will not be set.

The hash can be checked with

```
pdbedit -L -W
```

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX stands for not set.

Solution is also there [Ubuntu 20.04 "NO LanMan password set for user"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1344161/ubuntu-20-04-no-lanman-password-set-for-user/1363793#1363793)

Answer (score 0):

In order for `lanman auth = yes` to work, you must also set `ntlm auth = yes` for newer versions of Samba. [Edit: Of course, regenerating the password with smbpasswd after setting this is also required as noted in your question.]

I had encountered the same issue on FreeBSD, and stumbled across this email list [message](https://lists.samba.org/archive/samba/2019-May/223403.html) in my search, and am now able to poke around in my ZFS network share with Microsoft Network Client 3.0 in MS-DOS 6.22:

> Samba 4.7 changed 'lanman auth' to first honour 'ntlm auth', so you
> must set that as well.
>
> I'll prepare a documentation update.
>
> I've also confirmed that lanman passwords are still generated in our
> test environment.
>
> Andrew Bartlett